# $SO(n)$ Polar Decomposition for Matrices of Almost Positive Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to show that if $A$ is a limit point of $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R}) = \{A, \; n \times n \; | \; \det(A)>0\}$ then we can find a polar decomposition of $A = PU$ with $P$ symmetric semi-definite, and $U \in SO(n)$.  We are guaranteed that $U \in O(n)$ and it seems perfectly reasonable to me that there can be many candidates $U \in SO(n)$, but I'm having trouble proving this.  I'm sure it's a simple glaring oversight on my part.

The case when $A \in GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is quite simple.  Let $A = PU$ be a polar decomposition, then clearly $\det(A) = \det(P) \det(U) >0$ which only works when $U \in SO(n)$.  It's the case when $A$ is of diminished rank that I'm having trouble with.  I'm trying to prove something along the lines that if $A \in \overline{GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})}\setminus\{0\}$ we can write it as a sequence of matrices in $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ and use these polar decompositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Let $A$ be a limit point of $GL_n^+$, that is $A=\lim_k A_k$ where $A_k\in GL_n^+$ can be written $A_k=S_kO_k$ with $S_k$ symmetric $>0$ and $O_k\in SO(n)$. Note that $O(n)$ is compact and $SO(n)$ too (since it is closed). Let $(O_{k_j})_j$ be a convergent subsequence of $(O_k)_k$ and let $U=\lim_j O_{k_j}\in SO(n)$. The sequence $(S_{k_j})_j=(A_{k_j}O_{k_j}^T)_j$ converges to $S=AU^T$, a symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix (since the set of symmetric $\geq 0$ matrices is closed). Conclusion; $A=SU$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer is perfect, exactly what I needed.